# protractor-flake seems to rerun ALL tests and not only the failed test

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am using "protractor-flake@2.5.1" version and running my test. In my test few of test are failing but its running all the test again.
I am not using any custom reporter except the Allure reporting
Below is the command i have used to run.

```
protractor-flake --max-attempts=2 --color=magenta -- config.js




Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
  System info: host: 'INBEN10174', ip: '157.237.220.180', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
  Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\anuvrs\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10988_18536}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
  Session ID: c09e8a25628d5c3998434d31803f0aa8

Executed 2 of 8 specs (1 FAILED) (6 SKIPPED) in 2 mins 7 secs.
[13:05:04] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:05:04] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[13:05:04] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[13:05:04] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

Using standard to parse output
Re-running tests: test attempt 2
Re-running the following test files:
D:\jsout\specs\sitecomviewer\widgets\TrajectorySpec.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Protractor-flake parses the test output to tell what needs to be re-run. If said output isn't in a format it understands, it will re-run all the tests. I would say it's a good bet `Allure` changes the output, and thus...

Try removing `Allure` and find out.